# macOS 11 Pyenv Python 3.9.0 Install Error

Tags: terminal, homebrew, python

I am trying to install python 3.9.0 on macOS 11.0.1. I have the latest version of brew and the latest pyenv.

```
sids@Sids-MacBook-Pro ~ % pyenv install 3.9.0
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.9.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.0/Python-3.9.0.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.9.0...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.16 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/8s/jlqpkvqj21zcq8d5kw_ndz180000gn/T/python-build.20201129164129.61815
Results logged to /var/folders/8s/jlqpkvqj21zcq8d5kw_ndz180000gn/T/python-build.20201129164129.61815.log

Last 10 log lines:
  File "/private/var/folders/8s/jlqpkvqj21zcq8d5kw_ndz180000gn/T/python-build.20201129164129.61815/Python-3.9.0/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 210, in _main
    return _bootstrap(
  File "/private/var/folders/8s/jlqpkvqj21zcq8d5kw_ndz180000gn/T/python-build.20201129164129.61815/Python-3.9.0/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 129, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/private/var/folders/8s/jlqpkvqj21zcq8d5kw_ndz180000gn/T/python-build.20201129164129.61815/Python-3.9.0/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 38, in _run_pip
    return subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", code], check=True).returncode
  File "/private/var/folders/8s/jlqpkvqj21zcq8d5kw_ndz180000gn/T/python-build.20201129164129.61815/Python-3.9.0/Lib/subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/private/var/folders/8s/jlqpkvqj21zcq8d5kw_ndz180000gn/T/python-build.20201129164129.61815/Python-3.9.0/python.exe', '-c', '\nimport runpy\nimport sys\nsys.path = [\'/var/folders/8s/jlqpkvqj21zcq8d5kw_ndz180000gn/T/tmpqmtz59lr/setuptools-49.2.1-py3-none-any.whl\', \'/var/folders/8s/jlqpkvqj21zcq8d5kw_ndz180000gn/T/tmpqmtz59lr/pip-20.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl\'] + sys.path\nsys.argv[1:] = [\'install\', \'--no-cache-dir\', \'--no-index\', \'--find-links\', \'/var/folders/8s/jlqpkvqj21zcq8d5kw_ndz180000gn/T/tmpqmtz59lr\', \'--root\', \'/\', \'--upgrade\', \'setuptools\', \'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I am not sure why this error is occurring. Has it got something to do with the second to last line, where it includes: `/private/var/folders/8s/jlqpkvqj21zcq8d5kw_ndz180000gn/T/python-build.20201129164129.61815/Python-3.9.0/python.exe` It seems as though the .exe is being built, but I'm on macOS.

How do I fix this and install Python 3.9.0?

Answer (score -1):

You should go to python.org and click on the download 3.9.0 link. You'll get an option to load python 3.9.0. Follow the instructions there.